# I can't get the area of touch point in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: desktop-environments

I can't get the area of touch point in Ubuntu 20.04, but I can get the area of touch point in Ubuntu 16.04; What shall I do? Previous methods are as follows:

bool GraphicsView::viewportEvent(QEvent *event){
QEvent::Type type = event->type();

```
if(type == QEvent::TouchBegin || type == QEvent::TouchUpdate
   || type == QEvent::TouchEnd){

    QTouchEvent *pTouchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent*>(event);
    QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = pTouchEvent->touchPoints();

    int nId = 0;
    QColor penColor;

    foreach (const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint tp, touchPoints) {

        qDebug() << "id" << tp.id() << "触摸区域" << tp.ellipseDiameters() << "触摸点" << tp.pos();
    }
    return true;
}

return QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(event);
```

}

Comment: Check the Qt versions on both systems and if that feature is available in both versions.

Comment: You mention two Ubuntu operating systems (20.04 & 16.04), but have tagged the question as being about Ubuntu Touch (the phone OS) so please correct or clarify your question.  Ubuntu-Touch is a UBports OS that currently is still 16.04 based (the 20.04 port isn't yet completed).

Comment: The Qt versions on both systems are same.

Comment: The Qt5 versions in *xenial* and *focal* vary greatly and are not the same.

Comment: We use Qt5.15.2 on ubuntu (20.04 & 16.04.